# How to transform the following inequality into LMI (linear matrix inequality)?

Tags: matrices, inequality, matrix-equations, semidefinite-programming, linear-matrix-inequality

Let $B$, $C$, $W$ and $V$ be given (known) matrices with $V$
and $W$ being semidefinite positive. We would like to determine the
matrices $X$, $Z$ and $T$ by solving the following inequality 
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}Z+\begin{bmatrix}X^{T}VX & XC\\
C^{T}X & C^{T}V^{-1}C
\end{bmatrix} &  & \begin{bmatrix}X & 0\\
C^{T}V^{-1} & B
\end{bmatrix}\\
\\
\begin{bmatrix}X^{T} & V^{-1}C\\
0 & B^{T}
\end{bmatrix} &  & T-Z+\begin{bmatrix}V^{-1} & 0\\
0 & W^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}\succeq0.
\end{equation}

$Z$ and $T$ are also semidefinite positive. All the terms are linear
in the unknown matrices except $X^{T}VX$. It would have been very
trivial to solve this inequality if there was no $X^{T}VX$ in it.
Does anyone know how to transform this inequality into linear matrix
inequality (LMI) please? Or does anyone know how to solve this inequality
in order to determine the matrices $X$, $Z$ and $T$ please? Thanks.